# How to install a Bearer token with Behat on my Symfony API-Platform

Tags: php, symfony, behat, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm developing an API with API-Platform. Authentication is provided by Lexik bundle. First use case are functional. I test my three first use cases with Postman and it works.

- Step1: I access a protected page without token, I have a 401 error as expected.
- Step2: I ask a token.
- Step3: I access a protected page with a token, I received data as expected.

Now I want to install Behat and add features to reproduced my manual test with Postman, but I am not able to configure my JWT token correctly.

I read [the official documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/#testing-with-behat). And here is my two scenarios:

```
# features/books.feature
Feature: Books feature
  Scenario: Listing all books without authentication
    When I add "Content-Type" header equal to "application/json"
    And I add "Accept" header equal to "application/json"
    And I send a "GET" request to "/api/books/"
    Then the response status code should be 401
    And the response should be in JSON
    And the header "Content-Type" should be equal to "application/json"
    And the JSON nodes should contain:
      | message                 | JWT Token not found              |
  @loginAsAdmin
  @logout
  Scenario: Listing all books with admin authentication
    When I add "Content-Type" header equal to "application/json"
    And I add "Accept" header equal to "application/json"
    And I send a "GET" request to "/api/books/"
    Then the response status code should be 200
    And the response should be in JSON
    And the header "Content-Type" should be equal to "application/json"
```

[image: Behat test screenshot]

As you can see an screenshot, the first scenario works fine, but not the second, because my functional implementation is returning a 301 http code (redirection!) instead of 200.

> Current response status code is 301, but 200 expected.
>   I never had a 301 response with postman...

[image: Postman test]

Here is my method to declare @loginAsAdmin

```php
/**
 * FeatureContext constructor.
 *
 * @param KernelInterface $kernel the kernel to get services.
 */
public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
{
    $this->manager = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
    $this->jwtManager = $kernel->getContainer()->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager');
}

/**
 * @BeforeScenario @loginAsAdmin
 *
 * @see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#creating-your-first-user
 *
 * @param BeforeScenarioScope $scope the scope
 */
public function loginAsAdmin(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
{
    //Test with a fake user
    //$user = new User();
    //$user->setEmail('admin@example.org');
    //$user->setUsername('Admin');
    //$user->setRoles(['ROLE_ADMIN']);
    //Test with a user in database
    /** @var UserRepository $userRepository */
    $userRepository = $this->manager->getRepository(User::class);
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $userRepository->findOneByEmail('admin@example.org');
    $token = $this->jwtManager->create($user);
    /** @var RestContext $restContext */
    $this->restContext = $scope->getEnvironment()->getContext(RestContext::class);
    $this->restContext->iAddHeaderEqualTo('Authorization', "Bearer $token");
}

/**
 * @AfterScenario @logout
 */
public function logout() {
    $this->restContext->iAddHeaderEqualTo('Authorization', '');
}
```

I tried to use a virtual user (in comments)
I tried to use a user already set in database, it does not change anything.

As soon as I add header to my rest context, it seems to return a redirect answer. The redirection target is the same page : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/books

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596940/symfony-4-test-db-for-jwt-and-behat) which is a little different and it seems user does not have response for my case.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a joke! I only remove the trainling slash on /api/books/ and the redirection disappears.

```
Feature: Books feature
  Scenario: Listing all books without authentication
    When I add "Content-Type" header equal to "application/json"
    And I add "Accept" header equal to "application/json"
    And I send a "GET" request to "/api/books"
    Then the response status code should be 401
    And the response should be in JSON
    And the header "Content-Type" should be equal to "application/json"
    And the JSON nodes should contain:
      | message                 | JWT Token not found              |
  @loginAsAdmin
  @logout
  Scenario: Listing all books with admin authentication
    When I add "Content-Type" header equal to "application/json"
    And I add "Accept" header equal to "application/json"
    And I send a "GET" request to "/api/books"
    Then the response status code should be 200
    And the response should be in JSON
    And the header "Content-Type" should be equal to "application/json"
```